# Vanilla JS: Add class Baz to all <li> with class Foo if they contain a descendant <div> with class Bar

Tags: javascript, contains

Would like a vanilla JS solution, ie no jquery etc.

I have several

on page with the class *Foo*.

Some of these contain a  with the class *Bar* (not as a direct child).

I want to **add** the class *Baz* to any *Foo*

that contains a descendant  with class *Bar*.

Any assistance would be wonderful. Many thanks!

This is what I have so far. I am sure the **contains** syntax is where I am getting this wrong.

```
const addClassTo = document.querySelectorAll('li.foo').contains('div.bar');
addClassTo.forEach((element) => {element.classList.add('baz');})
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const addClassTo = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li.foo')).filter((ele) => ele.querySelector('div.bar'))
addClassTo.forEach((element) => {element.classList.add('baz');})
```

Comment: This is what I need - perfect!!! Thanks Chris. Now I can finally leave work! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would flip the logic - rather than trying to add a class to the parent if it contains the div with the target class - I would target the the div with the target class and then traverse up the ancestor tree to find the closest element with the class of 'foo' to add the class to provide the styling. This uses element.closest() - (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Here the div that contains the target div has a green border. This is because the parentNode of the element has been given the /baz/ class.

I have also added a non-foo div to demonstrate the selector is only querying .foo .bar elements. as well as a non-drect child div - to show the effect of the closest method traversing up the tree to the parent.

```js
const bazDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.foo .bar')


bazDivs.forEach((element) => {
   element.closest(".foo").classList.add('baz')
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
  border:solid 1px;
} 

div + div {
  margin-top: 8px;
} 

.foo {
  border-color: red;
}

.bar {
  border-color: blue;
}

.baz {
  border-color: green;
}

.not-foo {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
 does not have .bar
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    has .bar and is direct child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="other-div">
   <div class="bar">
      has .bar and is not direct child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
 does not have. bar
</div>

<div class="not-foo">
 does not have .foo or .bar
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Gavgrip :) Thanks for this! Can the parentNode approach work even if not a direct child?

Comment: Thanks - I have amended the solution to account for non-direct children -- using closest() will get the parent element with .foo - no matter how deeply nested the div is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:has` pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) to select a parent `.foo` that has a child `.bar`.

Example (based [gavgrif's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75611632/5157454)) - green border is a parent `.foo` with a child `.bar`:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.foo:has(.bar)')
  .forEach(el => {
    el.classList.add('baz')
  })
```

```css
div {
  padding: 8px;
  border:solid 4px;
} 

div + div {
  margin-top: 8px;
} 

.foo {
  border-color: red;
}

.bar {
  border-color: blue;
}

.baz {
  border-color: green;
}

.not-foo {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
 does not have .bar
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    has .bar and is direct child
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="other-div">
   <div class="bar">
      has .bar and is not direct child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
 does not have. bar
</div>

<div class="not-foo">
 does not have .foo or .bar
</div>
```